# Why are no Amazon S3 authentication handlers ready?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I have my $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables set properly, and I run this code:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3()
```

and get this error:

```
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler']
```

What's happening? I don't know where to start debugging.

---

It seems boto isn't taking the values from my environment variables. If I pass in the key id and secret key as arguments to the connection constructor, this works fine.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Boto **will** take your credentials from the environment variables. 
I've tested this with V2.0b3 and it works fine. It will give precedence to credentials specified explicitly in the constructor, but it will pick up credentials from the environment variables too.

The simplest way to do this is to put your credentials into a text file, and specify the location of that file in the environment.

For example (on Windows: I expect it will work just the same on Linux but I have not personally tried that)

Create a file called "mycred.txt" and put it into C:\temp
This file contains two lines:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=<your access id>
AWSSecretKey=<your secret key>
```

Define the environment variable **AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE** to point at C:\temp\mycred.txt

```
C:\>SET AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=C:\temp\mycred.txt
```

Now your code fragment above:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3()
```

will work fine.

Comment: Believe that you should also be able to supply kwargs on the connect verbs, for example:

boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region(
  myregion,
  aws_access_key_id=xxxx,
  aws_secret_access_key=yyyy)

Comment: I just posted an answer for Linux users that doesn't need environment variables.

Comment: There's more details on AWS credentials with `boto` at http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html

Answer (score 15):

I'm a newbie to both python and boto but was able to reproduce your error (or at least the last line of your error.)

You are most likely failing to export your variables in bash. if you just define then, they're only valid in the current shell, export them and python inherits the value. Thus:

```
$ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="SDFGRVWGFVVDWSFGWERGBSDER"
```

will not work unless you also add:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

Or you can do it all on the same line:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="SDFGRVWGFVVDWSFGWERGBSDER"
```

Likewise for the other value. You can also put this in your .bashrc (assuming bash is your shell and assuming you remember to export)

Comment: Where to put these details ? because I put these credentials in my settings.py. Is there any other setting ?

Answer (score 10):

Following up on nealmcb's answer on IAM roles. Whilst deploying EMR clusters using an IAM role, I had a similar issue where at times (not every time) this error would come up whilst connecting boto to s3.

```
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler']
```

The Metadata Service can timeout whilst retrieving credentials. Thus, as the docs suggest, I added a Boto section in the config and increased the number of retries to retrieve the credentials.  Note that the default is 1 attempt.

```
import boto, ConfigParser
try:
    boto.config.add_section("Boto")
except ConfigParser.DuplicateSectionError:
    pass
boto.config.set("Boto", "metadata_service_num_attempts", "20")
```

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html?highlight=retries#boto

Scroll down to: `You can control the timeouts and number of retries used when retrieving information from the Metadata Service (this is used for retrieving credentials for IAM roles on EC2 instances)`

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem we were having.  But note to others following -- make sure to import boto and ConfigParser to make the above work.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this problem while using Linux and SES, and I hope it may help others with a similar issue.  I had installed awscli and configured my keys doing:

```
sudo apt-get install awscli
aws configure
```

This is used to setup your credentials in ~/.aws/config just like @huythang said.  [But boto looks for your credentials in ~/.aws/credentials](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) so copy them over

```
cp ~/.aws/config ~/.aws/credentials
```

Assuming an appropriate policy is setup for your user with those credentials - you shouldn't need to set any environment variables.

Comment: On OSX, there was no need to rename `~/.aws/config`.

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/01/15/fabricboto-boto-exception-noauthhandlerfound-no-handler-was-ready-to-authenticate-1-handlers-were-checked-querysignaturev2authhandler-check-your-credentials/).

On Unix: first setup aws config:

```
#vim ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = Tokyo
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And set environment variables

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="aws_access_key_id"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="aws_secret_access_key"
```

Answer (score 3):

See latest [boto s3 introduction](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html):

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Comment: It is better not to include credentials explicitly in your code. You might forget that you have it there and check it into a public repository or even giving other people of your organization access to your credentials.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that in IAM "users by default have no permissions".  It took me all day to track that down, since I was used to the original AWS authentication model (pre-iam) in which what are now called "root" credentials were the only way.

There are lots of AWS documents on creating users, but only a few places where they note that you have to give them permissions for them to do anything.  One is [Working with Amazon S3 Buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html), but even it doesn't really just tell you to go to the Policies tab, suggest a good starting policy, and explain how to apply it.

The wizard-of-sorts simply encourages you to "Get started with IAM users" and doesn't clarify that there is much more to do.  Even if you poke around a bit, you just see e.g. *"Managed Policies There are no managed policies attached to this user."*  which doesn't suggest that you need a policy to do anything.

To establish a root-like user, see: 
[Creating an Administrators Group Using the Console - AWS Identity and Access Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/GSGHowToCreateAdminsGroup.html)

I don't see a specific policy which simply simply allows read-only access to all of S3 (my own buckets as well as public ones owned by others).

Comment: It is worth noting that  the username/identifier you assign S3 permissions to is a 64 character string

Answer (score 1):

You can now set these as arguments in the connect function call.

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Just thought I'd add that incase anyone else searched like I did.

Answer (score 1):

I had previously used `s3-parallel-put` successfully but it inexplicably stopped working, giving the error above. This despite having exported the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

The solution was to [specify the the credentials](http://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) in the boto config file:

```
$ nano ~/.boto
```

Enter the credentials like so:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, exporting keys need to look like this: `key=value`. So exporting, say, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environmental var should look like this: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=yourkey`. If you have any quotations around your values, as mentioned in above answers, boto will throw the above-mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with a flask application on ec2. I didn't want to put credentials in the application, but managed permission via IAM roles. That way can avoid hard-coding keys into code. Then I set a policy in the AWS console (I didn't even code it, I just used the policy generator)

My code is exactly like OP's. The other solutions here are good but there is a way to grand permission **without** hard-coding access keys.

1. Create an IAM security group that grants access to the S3 resource
2. Give the policy to the EC2 instance
3. Connect using nothing but `boto.connect_s3()` #no keys needed

Answer (score -4):

I see you call them `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

When it seems they should be set as `AWSAccessKeyId` & `AWSSecretKey`.

Comment: The versions with underscores are correct. 
http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html
http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/BotoConfig