# How to upload a file to directory in S3 bucket using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I want to copy a file in s3 bucket using python.

Ex : I have bucket name = test. And in the bucket, I have 2 folders name "dump" & "input". Now I want to copy a file from local directory to S3 "dump" folder using python... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer uses `boto`. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099059/913098) that uses `boto3`, which is [newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32323454/913098).

Try this...

```
import boto
import boto.s3
import sys
from boto.s3.key import Key

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''

bucket_name = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.lower() + '-dump'
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)


bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name,
    location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)

testfile = "replace this with an actual filename"
print 'Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % \
   (testfile, bucket_name)

def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()


k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'my test file'
k.set_contents_from_filename(testfile,
    cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

[UPDATE]
I am not a pythonist, so thanks for the heads up about the import statements.
Also, I'd not recommend placing credentials inside your own source code. If you are running this inside AWS use IAM Credentials with Instance Profiles (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html), and to keep the same behaviour in your Dev/Test environment, use something like Hologram from AdRoll (https://github.com/AdRoll/hologram)

Comment: I would avoid the multiple import lines, not pythonic.  Move the import lines to the top, and for the boto, you can use   from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection ; conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY); bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucketname...); bucket.new_key(keyname,...).set_contents_from_filename....

Comment: boto.s3.key.Key doesn't exist on 1.7.12

Comment: To upload files to an existing bucket, instead of creating a new one, replace this line:

bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name,
    location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)

With this code:

bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)

Answer (score 141):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET = "test"

s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file("your/local/file", "dump/file")
```

Comment: can you explain this line 
s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file("your/local/file", "dump/file")

Comment: @venkat "your/local/file" is a filepath such as "/home/file.txt" on the computer using python/boto and "dump/file" is a key name to store the file under in the S3 Bucket.  See: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_file

Comment: It looks like the user has pre-configured AWS Keys, to do this open your anaconda command prompt and type `aws configure`, enter your info and you will automatically connect with boto3. Check https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html

Comment: simplest solution IMO, just as easy as tinys3 but without the need for another external dependency. Also highly recommend setting up your AWS keys with `aws configure` ahead of time to make your life easier.

Comment: What happens when there are multiple profile in credentials. how to pass the specific credentials

Comment: does also work with non-preconfigured clients:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Answer (score 57):

Upload file to s3 within a session with credentials.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    aws_secret_access_key='AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
# Filename - File to upload
# Bucket - Bucket to upload to (the top level directory under AWS S3)
# Key - S3 object name (can contain subdirectories). If not specified then file_name is used
s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename='input_file_path', Bucket='bucket_name', Key='s3_output_key')
```

Comment: What is the s3_output_key?

Comment: It is the filename in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 50):

No need to make it that complicated:

```
s3_connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket('your bucket name')
key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, 'some_file.zip')
with open('some_file.zip') as f:
    key.send_file(f)
```

Comment: This will work, but for large .zip files you may need to use chunked.  http://www.elastician.com/2010/12/s3-multipart-upload-in-boto.html

Comment: Yes.. less complicated and commonly used practice

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work, but k.set_contents_from_filename(testfile,
    cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10) does

Comment: Are you on boto 2, latest? Anyway, set_contents_from_filename is an even simpler option. Go for it !

Comment: Is uploading a folder with lots of files different?

Comment: `key.set_contents_from_filename('some_file.zip')` would also work here. See [doc](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_filename). The corresponding code for boto3 can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#upload-a-file-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket).

Comment: I was getting 400 Bad Request from send_file() for some reason. set_contents_from_filename() worked fine on the other hand.

Answer (score 35):

I used this and it is very simple to implement

```
import tinys3

conn = tinys3.Connection('S3_ACCESS_KEY','S3_SECRET_KEY',tls=True)

f = open('some_file.zip','rb')
conn.upload('some_file.zip',f,'my_bucket')
```

https://www.smore.com/labs/tinys3/

Comment: I don't think this works for large files.  I had to use this: http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-large-data

Comment: That also led me to this fix: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2207#issuecomment-60682869 
and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396932/why-are-no-amazon-s3-authentication-handlers-ready

Comment: Since tinys3 project is abandoned you should not use this. https://github.com/smore-inc/tinys3/issues/45

Comment: This flat out didn't work for me anymore in 2019. tinys3 isn't just abandoned... I don't think it works anymore. For anyone else who decides to try this, don't be surprised if you get 403 errors. A simple `boto3.client` solution (like Manish Mehra's answer) worked immediately, though.

Answer (score 20):

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import boto3
#have all the variables populated which are required below
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
transfer = S3Transfer(client)
transfer.upload_file(filepath, bucket_name, folder_name+"/"+filename)
```

Comment: what is filepath and what is folder_name+filename? it's confusing

Comment: @colintobing filepath is path of file on cluster and folder_name/filename is the naming convention that you would want to have inside s3 bucket

Comment: @ManishMehra The answer would be better if you edited it to clarify colintobing's point of confusion; it's non-obvious without checking the docs which parameters refer to local paths and which ones to S3 paths without checking the docs or reading the comments. (Once that's done, you can flag to have all the comments here purged, since they'll be obsolete.)

Comment: `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` can also be configured with the AWS CLI and stored out of the script so that `client = boto3.client('s3') can be called

Answer (score 16):

This is a three liner. Just follow the instructions on the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file).

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource(service_name = 's3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename = 'C:/foo/bar/baz.filetype', Bucket = 'yourbucketname', Key = 'baz.filetype')
```

Some important arguments are:

**Parameters:**

**Filename** (`str`) -- The path to the file to upload.

**Bucket** (`str`) -- The name of the bucket to upload to.

**Key** (`str`) -- The name of the that you want to assign to your file in your s3 bucket. This could be the same as the name of the file or a different name of your choice but the filetype should remain the same.

**Note:** I assume that you have saved your credentials in a `~\.aws` folder as suggested in the [best configuration practices in the boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#best-practices-for-configuring-credentials).

Comment: Thank you Nde Samuel, that worked with me...One thing that was additional required in my case was to have the bucket already been created, to avoid an error of ""The specified bucket does not exist"".

Comment: @HassanSh__3571619 I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 13):

This will also work:

```
import os 
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

try:

    conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id = 'AWS-Access-Key',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'AWS-Secrete-Key',
    # host = 's3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    # is_secure=True,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
    calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
    )

    bucket = conn.get_bucket('YourBucketName')
    key_name = 'FileToUpload'
    path = 'images/holiday' #Directory Under which file should get upload
    full_key_name = os.path.join(path, key_name)
    k = bucket.new_key(full_key_name)
    k.set_contents_from_filename(key_name)

except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
    print "error"
```

Answer (score 9):

Using boto3

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

For more:-
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
END_POINT = ''                          # eg. us-east-1
S3_HOST = ''                            # eg. s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
BUCKET_NAME = 'test'        
FILENAME = 'upload.txt'                
UPLOADED_FILENAME = 'dumps/upload.txt'
# include folders in file path. If it doesn't exist, it will be created

s3 = boto.s3.connect_to_region(END_POINT,
                           aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                           aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                           host=S3_HOST)

bucket = s3.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = UPLOADED_FILENAME
k.set_contents_from_filename(FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 2):

For upload folder example as following code and S3 folder picture
[image]

```
import boto
import boto.s3
import boto.s3.connection
import os.path
import sys    

# Fill in info on data to upload
# destination bucket name
bucket_name = 'willie20181121'
# source directory
sourceDir = '/home/willie/Desktop/x/'  #Linux Path
# destination directory name (on s3)
destDir = '/test1/'   #S3 Path

#max size in bytes before uploading in parts. between 1 and 5 GB recommended
MAX_SIZE = 20 * 1000 * 1000
#size of parts when uploading in parts
PART_SIZE = 6 * 1000 * 1000

access_key = 'MPBVAQ*******IT****'
secret_key = '11t63yDV***********HgUcgMOSN*****'

conn = boto.connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
        host = '******.org.tw',
        is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name,
        location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)


uploadFileNames = []
for (sourceDir, dirname, filename) in os.walk(sourceDir):
    uploadFileNames.extend(filename)
    break

def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()

for filename in uploadFileNames:
    sourcepath = os.path.join(sourceDir + filename)
    destpath = os.path.join(destDir, filename)
    print ('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % \
           (sourcepath, bucket_name))

    filesize = os.path.getsize(sourcepath)
    if filesize > MAX_SIZE:
        print ("multipart upload")
        mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload(destpath)
        fp = open(sourcepath,'rb')
        fp_num = 0
        while (fp.tell() < filesize):
            fp_num += 1
            print ("uploading part %i" %fp_num)
            mp.upload_part_from_file(fp, fp_num, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10, size=PART_SIZE)

        mp.complete_upload()

    else:
        print ("singlepart upload")
        k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
        k.key = destpath
        k.set_contents_from_filename(sourcepath,
                cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

PS: For more reference [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664405/how-to-use-python-script-to-copy-files-from-one-bucket-to-another-bucket-at-the/53679657#53679657)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [aws command line interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/) installed on your system you can make use of pythons [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library.
For example:

```
import subprocess
def copy_file_to_s3(source: str, target: str, bucket: str):
   subprocess.run(["aws", "s3" , "cp", source, f"s3://{bucket}/{target}"])
```

Similarly you can use that logics for all sort of AWS client operations like downloading or listing files etc. It is also possible to get return values. This way there is no need to import boto3. I guess its use is not intended that way but in practice I find it quite convenient that way. This way you also get the status of the upload displayed in your console - for example:

```
Completed 3.5 GiB/3.5 GiB (242.8 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
```

To modify the method to your wishes I recommend having a look into the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) reference as well as to the [AWS Cli reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/).

Note: This is a copy of my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059769/uploading-files-to-s3-using-python/64713825#64713825).

Answer (score 1):

I have something that seems to me has a bit more order:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError


class S3(object):
    BUCKET = "test"
    connection = None

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            vars = get_s3_credentials("aws")
            self.connection = boto3.resource('s3', 'aws_access_key_id',
                                             'aws_secret_access_key')
        except(Exception) as error:
            print(error)
            self.connection = None


    def upload_file(self, file_to_upload_path, file_name):
        if file_to_upload is None or file_name is None: return False
        try:
            pprint(file_to_upload)
            file_name = "your-folder-inside-s3/{0}".format(file_name)
            self.connection.Bucket(self.BUCKET).upload_file(file_to_upload_path, 
                                                                      file_name)
            print("Upload Successful")
            return True

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("The file was not found")
            return False

        except NoCredentialsError:
            print("Credentials not available")
            return False
```

There're three important variables here, the **BUCKET** const, the **file_to_upload** and the **file_name**

`BUCKET`: is the name of your S3 bucket

`file_to_upload_path`: must be the path from file you want to upload

`file_name`: is the resulting file and path in your bucket (this is where you add folders or what ever)

There's many ways but you can reuse this code in another script like this

```
import S3

def some_function():
    S3.S3().upload_file(path_to_file, final_file_name)
```

Comment: $ pip install boto3 is required

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the content type as well to omit the file accessing issue.

```
import os
image='fly.png'
s3_filestore_path = 'images/fly.png'
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(image)
content_type_dict={".png":"image/png",".html":"text/html",
               ".css":"text/css",".js":"application/javascript",
               ".jpg":"image/png",".gif":"image/gif",
               ".jpeg":"image/jpeg"}

content_type=content_type_dict[file_extension]
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
                  region_name='ap-south-1',
                  aws_access_key_id=S3_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET)
s3.put_object(Body=image, Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=s3_filestore_path, ContentType=content_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlstr = etree.tostring(listings,  encoding='utf8', method='xml')
conn = boto.connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
        # host = '<bucketName>.s3.amazonaws.com',
        host = 'bycket.s3.amazonaws.com',
        #is_secure=False,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
conn.auth_region_name = 'us-west-1'

bucket = conn.get_bucket('resources', validate=False)
key= bucket.get_key('filename.txt')
key.set_contents_from_string("SAMPLE TEXT")
key.set_canned_acl('public-read')
```

Comment: A text explanation with what your code does will be nice!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the existing answers here are pretty complex. A simple approach is to use [`cloudpathlib`](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/), which wraps `boto3`.

First, be sure to be authenticated properly with an `~/.aws/credentials` file or environment variables set. See more options [in the cloudpathlib docs](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/authentication/).

This is how you would upload a file:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath

# write a local file that we will upload:
Path("test_file.txt").write_text("hello")
#> 5

# upload that file to S3
CloudPath("s3://drivendata-public-assets/testsfile.txt").upload_from("test_file.txt")
#> S3Path('s3://mybucket/testsfile.txt')

# read it back from s3
CloudPath("s3://mybucket/testsfile.txt").read_text()
#> 'hello'
```

Note, that you could write to the cloud path directly using the normal `write_text`, `write_bytes`, or `open` methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your example slightly, dropping some imports and the progress to get what I needed for a boto example.

```
import boto.s3
from boto.s3.key import Key

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your-access-key-id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your-secret-access-key'

bucket_name = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.lower() + '-form13'
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name, location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)
filename = 'embedding.csv'

k = Key(bucket)
k.key = filename
k.set_contents_from_filename(filename)
```

Here's a boto3 example as well:

```
import boto3

ACCESS_KEY = 'your-access-key'
SECRET_KEY = 'your-secret-key'

file_name='embedding.csv'
object_name=file_name
bucket_name = ACCESS_KEY.lower() + '-form13'

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
s3.upload_file(file_name, bucket_name, object_name)
```