# Python (Boto/tinys3) Upload file to AWS S3 bucket subdirectory

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

```
conn = tinys3.Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY,S3_SECRET_KEY)
f = open('sample.zip','rb')
conn.upload('sample.zip',f,bucketname)
```

I can upload the file to my bucket (test) via the code above, but I want to upload it directly to test/images/example. I am open to moving over to boto, but I can't seem to import boto.s3 in my environment.

I have looked through [How to upload a file to directory in S3 bucket using boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085864/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-s3-bucket-using-boto/41974925) but none of the tinys3 examples show this.

Comment: First, start using boto3 , because AWS deprecate boto and not support any third party module like tinys3, you will not get any support if you face any bug.  Second, take a look  http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

client.upload_file('/tmp/foo.txt', 'my-bucket', 'test/images/example/foo.txt')
```

Comment: Which line hangs? Hanging is normally an indication that the network connection is not working. Try doing it on a different network (eg home vs work).

Comment: It's not a network issue because I'm able to upload the file to the bucket but not the directory. client.upload_file('/tmp/foo.txt', 'my-bucket', 'test/images/example/foo.txt') is the line that hangs.

Comment: It works fine for me on a personal laptop and an EC2 instance. Check that you have the latest boto3 installed (sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade) and confirm the file paths and the AWS region (in the 2nd line).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
from boto3 import client


client_obj = client('s3',
                   aws_access_key_id='my_aws_access_key_id',
                aws_secret_access_key='my_aws_secret_access_key')
transfer = S3Transfer(client_obj)
transfer.upload_file(src_file,
                     'my_s3_bucket_name',
                     dst_file,
                     extra_args={'ContentType': "application/zip"})
```