# Amazon S3 connection with Django Heroku for image upload

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am a newbie to DevOps and deployment. I have created a CMS in Django which has an **image upload** option. The application is already deployed on **Heroku** and it uses **Postgres** database. I then got to know that Heroku is an **ephemeral filesystem** and all my images uploaded will be lost. So I need to connect it with S3 for image storage.

Can anyone give the **exact minimal code** specifics? I have searched and tried many tutorials but none of it seem to work completely. This might be silly question but **please help**. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Why rediscover the wheel if you have multiple django bundles made for this?

- Django [s3direct package](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct)
- a [nice guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) by Vitor Freitas
- Django [s3upload package](https://github.com/yunojuno/django-s3-upload)

All of these resources come with code examples.

Comment: These resources directly uploads the files to S3. But I need to do some image pre-processing before uploading to S3.

Comment: That is way too specific question to answer here. Image preprocessing is a separate issue from image uploading, unrelated with your original question. Also, you did not provide any details what kind of preprocessing you need to do for the images. Hence, it is impossible to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

s3 storage
create account in amazon.com

https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?nc2=h_m_mc&region=us-west-2

in s3 create bucket

https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#security_credential

take the access key

then do all the step here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Let me know if this does work :)

Comment: The tutorial is for Ruby. I'm using Django, Python.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085864/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-s3-bucket-using-boto

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django, the simplest way to upload files to S3 is to use django-storages library.

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html