# Get progress callback in aws boto3 uploads

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

There's a great question and answer for the original boto uploads here:

[How to upload a file to directory in S3 bucket using boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085864/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-s3-bucket-using-boto)

Which has a callback:

```
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'my test file'
k.set_contents_from_filename(testfile,
    cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

While I see the boto3 package takes a callback:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj

I don't see the equivalent of the num_cb argument.  How can I get a progress meter for `upload_fileobj` using boto3?

```
s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'mybucket', 'mykey')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to limit the number of calling callback, (and there is no way to do it with upload_fileobj),
1. show percentage

```
import os
import boto3

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.uploaded = 0
        self.s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    def upload_callback(self, size):
        if self.total == 0:
            return
        self.uploaded += size
        print("{} %".format(int(self.uploaded / self.total * 100)))

    def upload(self, bucket, key, file):
        self.total = os.stat(file).st_size

        with open(file, 'rb') as data:
            self.s3.upload_fileobj(
                data, bucket, key, Callback=self.upload_callback)
```

2. using progressbar

```
import os
import boto3
import progressbar


class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    def upload_callback(self, size):
        self.pg.update(self.pg.currval + size)

    def upload(self, bucket, key, file):
        self.pg = progressbar.progressbar.ProgressBar(
            maxval=os.stat(file).st_size)
        self.pg.start()

        with open(file, 'rb') as data:
            self.s3.upload_fileobj(
                data, bucket, key, Callback=self.upload_callback)
```