# Callback with Boto3, Showing Upload Progress

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am in a situation with a document storage feature in a Django/Python application (using Boto3) where I also need to provide the user with information on the progress of an upload.

The methods I have seen which use straight JS are not all universally 'usable' across browsers, what I want is to be able upload a file using Boto3 and then also show an upload progress bar in my Django template.

Looking at the docs here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html I am not understanding how it would be possible to show building progress of the upload calling `ProgressPercentage()` from within a template.

How would I go about displaying the actual progress for my user in a template using Boto3?

```
class ProgressPercentage(object):
        def __init__(self, filename):
            self._filename = filename
            self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
            self._seen_so_far = 0
            self._lock = threading.Lock()

        def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
            # To simplify we'll assume this is hooked up
            # to a single filename.
            with self._lock:
                self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
                percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
                sys.stdout.write(
                    "\r%s  %s / %s  (%.2f%%)" % (
                        self._filename, self._seen_so_far, self._size,
                        percentage))
                sys.stdout.flush()


transfer = S3Transfer(boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2'))
# Upload /tmp/myfile to s3://bucket/key and print upload progress.
transfer.upload_file('/tmp/myfile', 'bucket', 'key',
                         callback=ProgressPercentage('/tmp/myfile'))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three related answers in SO:

1. [Get progress callback in aws boto3 uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981929/get-progress-callback-in-aws-boto3-uploads)
   (couldn't make it work, but seems elegant)
2. [Track download progress of S3 file using boto3 and callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827963/track-download-progress-of-s3-file-using-boto3-and-callbacks)
   (this one is for downloads, but helped me understand what the
   callback should look like)
3. [S3 Python Download with Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549681/s3-python-download-with-progress-bar)
   (worked, I used this one to write my code).

Here is what I did that worked:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError, ClientError
import os
import progressbar

ACCESS_KEY = 'MY_ACCESS_KEY'
SECRET_KEY = 'MY_SECRET_KEY_THAT_I_KNOW_SHOULD_NOT_BE_HERE_BUT_I_HAVENT_IMPLEMENTED_THE_PROPER_WAY_YET_ALSO_I_DO_NOT_KNOW_WHY_I_AM_YELLING_SORRY'

def upload_to_aws(local_file, s3_bucket, s3_folder, s3_filename,force_overwrite='n'):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)


    def write_to_aws():

        statinfo = os.stat(local_file)
        up_progress = progressbar.progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=statinfo.st_size)
        up_progress.start()

        def upload_progress(chunk):
            up_progress.update(up_progress.currval + chunk)


        try:
            print("Writting")
            s3.upload_file(local_file, s3_bucket, s3_folder+s3_filename, Callback=upload_progress)
            print("Upload Successful")
            return True
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("The source file was not found")
            return False
        except NoCredentialsError:
            print("Credentials not available")
            return False
    try:
        s3.head_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_folder+s3_filename)
        if force_overwrite=='y':
            write_to_aws
        else:
            ask_overwrite = input('File already exists at destination. Overwrite?')
            if ask_overwrite == 'y':
                write_to_aws()
            else:
                print('leaving application')
    except ClientError as e:
        write_to_aws()
```

I know you probably figured that out already, but if anyone else finds this while searching for the solution, I hope this helps