# how to write airflow error logs into s3 bucket using python

Tags: python

when my airflow dag fails i get the errors in the path 
"/home/ec2-user/software/airflow/logs/dagtest_dag/trigger_load/2019-10-10T06:01:33.342433+00:00/1.log
"

how to take these log to s3 bucket?

Comment: You can fire up a service to package your logs and post them to s3.

Comment: There's this module called `boto` in python which can do this, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085864/how-to-upload-a-file-to-directory-in-s3-bucket-using-boto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure this as a cron job.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
# Make sure your client is authenticated
with open('path/to/your/logs.log', 'rb') as data:
    s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'bucketname', 'path/to/your/logs/in/s3.log')
```

Comment: what about dynamic calling of dags, as i cant give static right?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what do you mean by dynamic calling of dags?

Comment: with open('path/to/your/logs.log', 'rb') as data:
    s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'bucketname', 'path/to/your/logs/in/s3.log') This works only for particular dag ,if I run multiple dags i need update of all logs to s3

Comment: You can loop through your dags, and create path in s3 such as `dag_name/yyyy/mm/dd/filename.log`