# Connecting to S3 using Boto - No handler was ready to authenticate

Tags: python, django, heroku, boto

I'm setting up a Django app on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) and want to store media files on S3. I'm using [Python's Boto module](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) and keep on running into the same error:

**Error:**

```
No handler was ready to authenticate. 
1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

I've tried saving my credentials

(a) in my `Heroku config file` and using `os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]`

(b) in my `settings.py` file and

(c) in a separate .boto file as per the documentation.

Here is are the relevant parts of my settings.py, with the credentials in the file itself:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': "os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')",   # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

#config for S3
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'companylistings'
#AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
S3_URL = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/%s' %S3_BUCKET_NAME


MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + MEDIA_ROOT

STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_ROOT

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396932/why-are-no-amazon-s3-authentication-handlers-ready

Answer (score 1):

If it is on windows please follow this:

Install:`pip install awscli`

Open cmd and type:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID: 'your Access Key ID'
AWS Secret Access Key: 'your Secret Access Key'
Default region name: us-east-1
Default output format: json

$ manage.py shell
>>import boto
>>s3 = boto.connect_s3()
```

no error message shown. it's done

Details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-quick-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Check the bucket setting you have :

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME
```

my working configuration is :

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Try this!

My full config is :

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'PRIVATE'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'PRIVATE'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'PRIVATE'
```