# NoAuthHandlerFound AWS boto ec2 - With env variables set

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting what seems to be quite a common error for people starting with AWS, python and boto.

```
NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396932/why-are-no-amazon-s3-authentication-handlers-ready) and [this](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) but still get the error.

I know the credentials work and are correct because I have used them to test previous things such as an rds connections.

Script for rds is the following:

```
import boto.rds as rds
import boto3 as b3
import boto
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = boto.rds.connect_to_region("us-west-2",aws_access_key_id='<ID>',aws_secret_access_key='<KEY>')

engine = create_engine('postgresql://my_id:my_pass@datawarehouse.stuff.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/db_name', echo=False)

res = engine.execute("select * from table")

print res,engine
```

Which runs without error.

Is there anything I am missing in terms of VPC? Access rights?

Its making me nuts!

I have `BOTO_CONFIG` set to `C:/Users/%USER%/boto.config` at the user level (not system level).

and `C:/Users/%USER%/boto.config` reads as:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <MY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <MY_SECRET>
```

`print boto.__version__`
 yields:

```
2.40.0
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are your Credentials stored?Can you paste the path ti your credentials file here? And also the version of Boto you are using.

Comment: @error2007s I updated the question to be a transparent.

Comment: Change the name of boto.config to credentials.config and check it will work